# Honda XR650l first ride after winterization

Tags: engine, honda, motorcycle, winter

Before winter I had the oil changed, filled the gas tank and added the recommended amount of `Sta-bil` fuel stabilizer. Then rode around for about ten minutes then switched the petcock to `off` and ran the rest of the gas out of the system. Then the last step was draining the float bowl. Just for some context I should say this was my first time winterizing a bike, and I am less then knowledgeable about mechanics in general.

After being stored for many months, it is time for the first ride. Trying to start it for the first time this spring there is a little trouble ... the petcock is back in the `on` position and everything else seems okay, but the engine will not turn. I am not sure of the mechanisms involved with starting, but hitting the start switch will make a sound that indicates to me that everything electrical is working.

Is there something I am missing? Do I need to get fuel back into the float bowl somehow? any other tips for winterization and first spring rides?

Comment: The engine turning should have nothing to do with fuel. Did you disconnect (remove?) the battery before leaving the bike? Check battery connections and recharge battery.

Comment: I agree with @jensgram ... we'll need more exacting information as to what is happening. Right now you are talking apples and oranges. It sounds like from your question it has something to do with the battery, not the flow of gas. As for that part of your winterization, I'd say you did a great job from that aspect. It's basically what I do with my small engines.

Comment: Check the kill switch. Most bikes will allow the starter to turn the engine over even though the ignition is disabled.

Comment: @jensgram it is the battery... should have known. I did not setup a trickle charger or take any precautions for a dead battery -Peter I have learned to check the kill switch when she wont start a long time ago :)

Comment: Please put your comment down as the answer. It seems you figured out what the problem was so you may as well get credit for it.

Answer (score 3):

From the comments above.

OP Solved the Issue.

The OP discovered that this was a battery related issue and did not put the battery on a trickle charger of the winter idle period.  As a result the battery completely drained and was unable to be recharged.

The OP did not respond to putting in the answer as a result I have populated it.